# Find indexes in bool array changed from false to true?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, boolean

I have two arrays:

```
bool[] oldValues = GetCurrentValuesFromSomewhere ();

ChangeCurrentValues ();

bool[] newValues = GetCurrentValuesFromSomewhere ();

List<int> whichIndexsHasBeenChangedFromFalseToTrue = /* linq */
```

Any idea? Instead of list, it can be `bool[]` array too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do use something like this:

```
var changedValues =
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, oldValues.Length)
     where !oldValues[i] && newValues[i]
     select i)
    .ToList();
```

Or if you prefer fluent syntax:

```
var changedValues = Enumerable
     .Range(0, oldValues.Length)
     .Where(i => !oldValues[i] && newValues[i])
     .ToList();
```

If you wanted a `bool[]` result, you can use this:

```
var changedValues =
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, oldValues.Length)
     select !oldValues[i] && newValues[i])
    .ToArray();
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var changedValues = Enumerable
     .Range(0, oldValues.Length)
     .Select(i => !oldValues[i] && newValues[i])
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: I will test it in a minute. But should it be Length - 1 in Range?

Comment: @zgnilec No, the second argument is the count of integers to return, not the maximum integer to return. E.g. `Enumerable.Range(0, 5)` returns `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.

Comment: You could go to `Math.Min(oldValues.Length, newValues.Length)` if it's possible that they're not the same size, but that may not be an issue in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer using the lambda that gives you the index, so you do not have to generate the range:

```
 var changed = newValues.
     Select((value, index) => oldValues[index] == value ? -1 : index).
     Where(i => i >= 0);
```

This should return a list of the indexes that have changed; `.Count()` will give you how many values have changed.

UPDATE: An alternative version

```
 var changed = newValues.
     Select((value, index) => 
        value ? (oldValues[index] ? 0 : index + 1) : (oldValues[index] ? - (index + 1) : 0)).
     Where(i => i != 0);
```

Will give you as `index+1` those values that were `false` and are now `true`, and as `-(index + 1)` those values that were `true` and now are `false`. I am learning LINQ myself so I like to play with it quite a bit.

Comment: Yeah, my answer ended up bloating beyond sanity. This is far better.

Comment: this just detects changes (doesn't care about from `false` to `true` or `true` to `false`). While the OP's question requires from `false` to `true` (although looks like all the old values are `false`).

Comment: @KingKing I was updating the answer while you where writting your comment, check it now.

Comment: @KingKing: That's true, but this does give the correct methodology. Fixing a conditional is something anyone who has reached the point of asking a question like this should understand how to do.

Comment: @AlexBeisley I talked about the first. If methodology is needed, the answers posted before can do. BTW, it can be simpler that you just need to change the first a little at the `Select` like this `value&&!oldValues[index] ? index : -1`

Answer (score 0):

If there are always the same number of new and old, and you're just doing a diff, which is what you seem to be doing, I'd do something like this:

```
int index;
whichIndexsHasBeenChangedFromFalseToTrue = oldValues.Zip(newValues, (old, new) => 
  {
    int result = -1;
    if(old != new) result = index;
    index++;
    return result;
  }).Where(x => x != -1);
```

This is only for changed, but if you specifically want false to true, that's just a change to the if.

EDIT: Fixed a serious issue.